# constructors different invocation result in java

Tags: java, constructor

I'm working with some simple exercises in Java and I noticed that in general when I use a constructor, I will have to invoke it like this in the main method:

```
ConstructorName object = new ConstructorName();  
object.methodName();
```

BUT I don't understand something...when I have a class with only this methods:
1. `public FrameBuilder()` //which is the constructor and is responsible for building the frame
2. `public void paintComponent(Graphics g)` // which builds a panel
3. `public static void main(String[] args) 
           { new FrameBuilder(); }`

Why are the panel and the frame created in the same time??? I mean I thought it should be:

```
new FrameBuilder().paintComponent(Graphics g);
```

in order to work correctly just like the other cases when you should specify the method name that the object will have to execute...

I really want to know the reason for this "behavior", so if someone knows the answer please share it!

Comment: Without any context it's difficult to understand what you're asking.

Comment: It would be beneficial to see the source code of the `FrameBuilder` class, or at least the name of the API it comes from.

Answer (score 0):

The `FrameBuilder()` constructor is calling `paintComponent(Graphics g)` from inside the constructor. Therefore when you call the constructor, it calls `paintComponent(Graphics g)` for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The reason why I was confused was because I didn't create DIRECTLY a panel in the constructor, but I called it with: frame.getContentPane().add(this); which is the same thing (I feel silly :/)